# how to get the windows 7 graphic effect?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I have installed Windows 7 on my machine and all the hardware has been initialised. However my graphics hardware does not have full functionality. How do I find out which of the standard drivers Windows installs need to be updated for the hardware in my machine to work as intended?

Comment: I think this is to do with the basic Drivers Windows installed not having full functionality on his machine. Could be quite a useful question with a quick tidy up. Lots of people don;t get full functionality from their hardware because Windows installs the default drivers so they don't know / bother to upgrade them to the correct drivers

Comment: Changing your question to something like this would probably be more acceptable -> I have installed Windows 7 on my machine and all the hardware has been initialised. However my graphics hardware does not have full functionality. How do I find out which of the standard drivers Windows installs need to be updated for the hardware in my machine to work as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the correct drivers for your chipset or has Windows just installed the standard VGA driver? I imagine it will have just installed the standard VGA driver and when you update the drivers to the correct version you will be able to get the Aero affect

To Find out which hardware is in your machine do this:

- Go into Device Manager. (Right click my computer, click manage, select device manager from the left hand side)
- Expand Display adapters
- Double click the adapter
- Select the Details tab
- Select Hardware IDs from the dropdown box

This is the Hardware identifier for your device. Using the website [PCIDatabase.com](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) you can find the type of drivers you need. Often googling the code will also bring you to the drivers you need. If you are struggling simply post the PCI code and I'll try and help further

Comment: how i'm able to find out driver name which my system support, because my driver CD not contain windows7 driver.

Comment: I believe a Windows Vista driver will work. Otherwise, check the web site of the manufacturer of the graphics card; they might (d* well should) have Win7 drivers available.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open device manager.
2. If you have no driver installed, you should see a "VGA Controller" under Unknown devices. OR if you have a driver installed, it should appear under "Display adapters"
3. If it is unknown, double click on VGA controller. Click Details > Property > Hardware IDs
4. Paste the details here. (Starting with PCI..._